# How to set different color in a select box due to selection with css

Tags: css, options, select

I have a select box with 2 options. In the selct area the options are
green for 1
red for 2

I had been able to set green also as the color for the predefined option.
Now I would like to change this due to the incoming selection.

That means, if someone has 1 as predefined selection the color of the appearing conent of the shown select box should be green and if some has 2 as redefined selection the color of the appearing conent of the shown select box should be red.

https://jsfiddle.net/aqd7web5/2/

The whole thing only with css if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding an onchange event to your select tag. 
 Try the code below:

**HTML:** 
<select id="derselect" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className"
    class="green"> 
    <option class="green">Test 1
    <option class="red">Test 2
</select>

**And your CSS:** 
.green { color:green} 
.red {color:red}

:)

Comment: Thanks, but It seems not to work

https://jsfiddle.net/h6vfL7wb/

Comment: I checked your fiddle. You're not using the example I shared right. Check again

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use some jQuery to do that easy, exemple:

```
<Select id="select_opt">
  <Option value="green">first</option>
  <Option value="red"> Second </option>
</Select>
```

Then when your document is ready

```
$('#select_opt').on('change', 'option' , function{ 

       $(this).attr('style' , 'text-color:' + $(this).val());

});
```

Comment: You need to do that dynamicly, css is static in events, text color change when event happen and css don't suport user events.